# Sequelize is returning this as response [{'primaryKey':null}] to findAll method

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am using ES6 classes to define my sequelize models as suggested by this post

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6524#issuecomment-329664805

But I am facing this issue after writing a simple api call on express to fetch data from that table, It is generating the exact query which produces the right results that I want but it is sending this as response not the right results:

```
[{"attribute30":null}]
```

`attribute30` is my primary key.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved as I was using ES6 classes and inheritance in the model classes so the constructor defined by the Sequelize had some arguments, so in the child classes I has to include the 'arguments' in the super().